# How can manage errors professionally to my users

Tags: php, error-handling

I am writing a custom cms for personal stuff and to use in my future projects. One thing is getting into my nerves: error handling. I use sessions to show the use errors such as invalid email, you are not logged in.

```
$as_errmsg_arr[] = "Either your username or password is wrong.";
$as_errflag = true;
$_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR'] = $as_errmsg_arr;
```

then when displaying the eror I decode the error so as to show to the user like this:

```
if( isset($_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) 
{ 
    echo '<p class="err_msg">';                             
        foreach($_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR'] as $as_error_msg) echo $as_error_msg.'<br>';
    echo '</p>';
    unset($_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR']);
}
```

this was working well before but now as my project is getting bigger it fails terrible yet it is very crucial. when I remove the line:

> unset($_SESSION['AS_ERRMSG_ARR']);

the error generated is shown. I would appreciate some explanation and even direction on how I can solve this issue.

Comment: Do you want show prev step validations errors?

Comment: No I that will not be necessary for me